# Metamask is not showing the ethereum address balance on local geth instance

Tags: ethereum, geth, metamask

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start local geth node with following command: `geth --rinkeby
   --rpc --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1"`
2. Connect metamask chrome extension to `http://localhost:8545`
3. Create a new ethereum account, ABC,  on metamask
4. New account is visible on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io
5. Transfer some ethereum to ABC on rinkeby network
6. On Metamask, we can see ABC balance is increased on rinkeby network
7. However, we see ABC balance as zero, **no change on localhost:8545**

We checked the block number on local instance of geth, it is greater than the transaction block, so this means new block is downloaded to local instance of geth.

We couldnot figure out why Metamask is still showing the balance 0 when it is connected to localhost:8545. Your helps are appreciated.

[Etherscan image](https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/01/24/289CG.png)

[Block image](https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/01/24/28dUt.png)

[Metamask image](https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/01/24/2lnSP.png)

[Metamask error image](https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/01/24/2lR9N.png)